# How to eject ipod in itunes 12.1

Tags: ipod, eject

There doesn't appear to be an eject button on the new 12.1 menu screen.  Is this correct, or have I missed it?

Answer (score 1):

Right of the device's icon, when you're in the appropriate 'device' section on the top row...

[image]